# Can we add attribute for wordpress menu <li>

Tags: wordpress

i have an HTML menu like this

```
<ul id="menu-main-menu" class="menu">
<li class="current_page_item"> <a href="index.html"> Home </a> </li>
<li class="menu-item-simple-parent"> <a href="aboutus.html">About us &nbsp <i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i></a>
     <ul class="sub-menu" style="left:0px;width:340px;">
        <li data-content="mission"> <a href="#">Mission</a> </li>
        <li data-content="vision"> <a href="#">Vision</a>  </li>
        <li data-content="management"> <a href="#">Management</a> </li>
    </ul>
</li>
```

I created this menu in wordpress. In that, submenu created as custom link. can I add data-content attribute for my wordpress submenu as shown in HTML code.

Comment: These 2 links might be helpful for you. [Link 1](http://www.wpexplorer.com/adding-custom-attributes-to-wordpress-menus/) , [Link 2](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/121123/how-to-add-a-data-attribute-to-a-wordpress-menu-item)

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
add_filter( 'nav_menu_link_attributes', 'themeprefix_menu_attribute_add', 10, 3 );
function themeprefix_menu_attribute_add( $atts, $item, $args )
{
  // Set the menu ID
  $menu_link = 1215;
  // Conditionally match the ID and add the attribute and value
  if ($item->ID == $menu_link) {
    $atts['data-toggle'] = 'modal';
  }
  //Return the new attribute
  return $atts;
}
```

Tutorial -> https://wpbeaches.com/adding-attribute-wordpress-menu-item/

Comment: This add attributes on the href, not the li.